# Visualization of a set

Tags: graphing-functions, visualization

> How can I imagine the set
>   $$
> M:=\left\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:z=xy\right\}?
> $$

Is there a program that can visualize that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can notice that $z=xy=x_1^2-x_2^2$ for $x_1=\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $x_2=\frac{x-y}{\sqrt{2}}$. Using $x_1$ and $x_2$ instead of $x$ and $y$ is simply [rotating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_%28mathematics%29) the coordinate system by $45^\circ$.

Now if $x_2=0$ then $z=x_1^2$ is a parabola. So we already know some of the points of the graph. Now simply imagine that on each point of this parabola you hang downward directed parabola. (Since for any fixed $x_1$ the function $z=x_1^2-x_2^2$ is again a parabola, but with a different orientation.)

In this way you get something looking like a saddle. This surface is called [hyperbolic paraboloid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_paraboloid).

On this picture the parabolas in both directions are nicely visible:

[image]

I've taken the picture from [this site](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/QuadricSurfaces.aspx). I found it simply by searching for
[hyperbolic paraboloid](http://images.google.com/images?q=hyperbolic+paraboloid) in Google Images.

Answer (score 5):

Having taught a multivariable calc class I usually tell my students to try to picture "slices" of the function. What I mean by this is choose a variable. In this case $x$ is a good choice. Then assume $x=1$, do the same for $x=2$ and so on. In each case you get a line and as you do this for all $x$ and "put them together" you get the picture you want.

Answer (score 4):

In http://www.wolframalpha.com/ put "Plot z=xy" and see the result!

Answer (score 3):

The final shape is your set. I did it by Maple 16 as follows:

```
[> with(plots):
[> P := animate(plot3d, [k*x*y, x = -200 .. 200, y = -200 .. 200], k = 0 .. 100, frames = 60, axes = boxed):
[> display([P], insequence = true);
```

[image]

Comment: Whoa, animated graphic. You've gone "all out"! ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: I was not sure if anybody could see it animated. But, I am sure the site can render the gif file. Thanks ;-)